# Impossible to undeploy CustomCode jar (and therefore impossible to deploy a newer version)

Tags: java, mobile, paas, mbaas, app42

I am giving a try with the [app42 PaaS solution from Shephertz](http://api.shephertz.com/app42-dev.php), and especially its [CustomCode feature](http://api.shephertz.com/tutorial/Server-Side-Custom-Code/?index=customcode,wrd) to deploy Java server-side code.

I managed to correctly deploy one version of my server-side "CustomCode" jar (using "ant deploy" command, like in [the provided sample](https://github.com/shephertz/App42_CustomCode_Sample/)).

The problem is that I can't undeploy it

- either from the "ant undeploy" command, cf. this error

[image]
(the html returned looking like this)
[image]

- or from the App42 management console (POST is successful but returns failure message)
[image]

Obviously, this prevents me to deploy a new version of this jar, cf. this error
[image]

Answer (score 0):

It has been answered at our forum here. See this http://forum.shephertz.com/index.php/57/impossible-undeploy-customcode-therefore-impossible-version?show=57#q57